# How to hide header , footer and other tags with Webview in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, webview, jsoup

I have used Jsoup for hide html tags (header, search panel, footer) . All work fine. But when i click any ithem, in new page will show footer and header again. How to i can hide header and footer for all operations ? 
Thanks for before :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webview;
    String url="http://hut.az/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);



        new MyAsynTask().execute();

    }

    private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Document document = null;
            try {
                document= Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                document.getElementsByClass("header1").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("topbar clearfix").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("mapandslider").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("footer1").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("copyright").remove();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return document;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
            super.onPostExecute(document);
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );

            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                private WebView view;
                private WebResourceRequest request;

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    this.view = view;
                    this.request = request;
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```